# Permanent pet spider: Pros and cons

Tags: torchlight

I have caught a giant web fish. It allows me to permanently turn my pet into a pet spider. Do I lose anything by doing this except the cuddly looks of my companion? What are the benefits of having a permanent pet spider? (Does it then keep those benefits if i feed it other fish to turn it into other creatures temporarily?)

Is there any advantage to turning your pet permanently into a spider if you have piles of web fish to keep turning it into a spider temporarily?

Comment: As far as I can see, the huge, massive, overwhelming con is that my pet would stop being an alpaca.  I love that freaking alpaca.  I even gave him a fireball spell so he'd be a fire breathing alpaca.

Comment: @Christi haha, I gave my kitty a fireball as well.

Comment: (Note: the alpaca only exists in Torchlight II.  Poor alpaca deprived TLI.)

Comment: I don't even remember the Alpaca in TL2.  Is that a fish-produced pet?

Comment: The Alpaca was added when TL2 finally added mod support (GUTS). They added the Alpaca, Headcrab(HL2), Panda, and the Stag too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permanent is relative here, if you ever feed your pet another transformation fish he'll go back to his original form once that one runs out.

The only advantages I know of it is that you can then sell these webfish (for whatever they earn you) and you don't have to micromanage your pet eating things anymore.

The default pet has a small disadvantage to the "fished" up pet in all cases, the spider pet has his web, the crab his bonus defenses,...